# Unity2d Sprite shows in scene but not game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've searched for the above title and have tried a few different resolutions but still doesn't seem to be able to resolve this issue. here is a screenshot http://puu.sh/oGqsp.jpg showing that the sprite is showing in the scene but in the game its isn't there. Furthermore i've tried to individually hide elements in the Game to see if i can find the player sprite but it seems to not be under anything either in the build, still shows in scene. Here is a screenshot of it showing in scene and a near empty game scene but still wont show. http://puu.sh/oGsBy.png

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the properties of the sprite that is disappearing, as well?

Comment: If you mean the player sprite's inspector properties http://puu.sh/oGuSA.jpg here they are when it is instantiated during play

Comment: Hmm, all right. How about the tiles, what do their properties look like?